# Javascript map inside of map till condition satisfied

Tags: javascript

I like to pass id then get number of all descendant items. e.g. if pass `10` it will return `2` because there's 2 items `{ id: 7, report: 10 }` and `{ id: 4, report: 7 }`.

```
let Data = [
  { id: 10, report: -1 },
  { id: 7, report: 10 },
  { id: 3, report: -1 },
  { id: 4, report: 7 }
];
```

This code only works for the Data above but won't work if there's more data added such as `{ id: 5, report: 4 }`. How do I make this work?

```
function countItems(id){
  let count = 0;

  Data.map( em => {
    if(em.report === 10) {
      count++
      
      orgChart.map( ema => {
        if(ema.report === em.id) {
          count++
        }
      })
      
    }
  })

  return count;
}
```

Comment: why would you use map for this, rather than a dedicated function that can follow the data trail while incrementing a counter until the trail stops? And having said that: making sure to start with a good data structure can make a hard problem almost trivially easy: rewrite that `Data` object to a reverse lookup, and things become a lot easier.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by deeper level. The object you show is only one level. Please show the nested structure if that's what you're unable to search in.

Comment: I thought I understood, but I'm confused now too given the example mentioned. Could you provide any more clarity about what the function should count exactly?

Comment: `data.sort((a, b) => (a.id === b.report) - (a.report === b.id))` should sort all parents behind their child, so you can always use the id to find the next report.

Comment: @zcoop98 maybe it's clearer if you swap the properties: { report: 10, id: 7 } { report: 7, id: 4 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat each each object finding as a separate task. If one object is found then check if the next object is available or not untill no object is available with that id.

```
// Using recursion
function countItems(id, data){
    for (const item of data){
        if(item.report == id){
            return 1 + countItems(item.id, data);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


let data = [
  { id: 10, report: -1 },
  { id: 7, report: 10 },
  { id: 3, report: -1 },
  { id: 4, report: 7 }
];
   
console.log(countItems(10, data)); // it will print 2
console.log(countItems(-1, data)); // it will print 3

// Using Loop
function countItemsUsingLoop(id, data){
    count  = 0;
    found = false;
    do{
        found = false;
        for (const item of data){
          if(item.report == id){
          found = true;
          id = item.id;
          count++;
          break;
          }
        }
    }while(found);
    return count;
}

console.log(countItemsUsingLoop(10, data)); // it will print 2
console.log(countItemsUsingLoop(-1, data)); // it will print 3
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm learning JS. Can you please share a solution with the loop? I want to see how to do it in other ways too if you don't mind.

Comment: Updated the answer with method using loop instead of recursion. @Ohsik

Answer (score 0):

A more declarative approach:

```js
const countItems = (id, data) => {
  const datum = data.find(({ report }) => report == id);
  return datum ? 1 + countItems(datum.id, data) : 0;
}
```